# SQL find lack of specific string against multiple ID's in same table

Tags: sql

```
ID  can eat
1   apples
1   pears
2   grapes
2   pears
3   apples
3   oranges
3   pears
4   oranges
5   apples
6   pears
6   oranges
```

Using the above table as an example of data. How can I find the ID of all people who cannot eat apples?

Comment: Please try yourself first, when you get problems with that, we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `id` and take only those groups having no `apples` entry

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case when can_eat = 'apples' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the id's `except` those who can eat apples:

```
select id from tablename
except
select id from tablename where caneat = 'apples'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sheet1.ID
FROM Sheet1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Sheet1.ID
FROM Sheet1
WHERE (((Sheet1.caneat)="apples"))
GROUP BY Sheet1.ID)  AS CanEatApplesList ON Sheet1.ID = CanEatApplesList.ID
WHERE (((CanEatApplesList.ID) Is Null))
GROUP BY Sheet1.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the simplest version of possible solutions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
FROM TableName a
WHERE can_eat NOT in ('apples') 
AND a.ID NOT in (SELECT distinct b.ID
FROM TableName b WHERE b.can_eat = 'apples');
```